# error C2046: illegal case

Tags: c++, case

I have been looking for quite some time for an answer to this, and I haven't found one so i decided to ask.  For some reason I'm getting an illegal case statement error.  This is for my final project and my teacher can't even find the error. It was working fine before, but after it put in something then took it out, the case statement stopped working...even though the code's the same...

```
         do //start of do while loop
{
cout << "Welcome to the Sperry Store!" << '\n'; //greeting

cout << " " << '\n';
cout << "1-  Men's Authentic Original Seasonal Boat Shoe.. $79.99" << '\n';
cout << "2-  Men's Authentic Original Suede Boat Shoe..... $64.99" << '\n';
cout << "3-  Men's Mako 2-Eye Canoe Moc Boat Shoe......... $70.00" << '\n';
cout << "4-  Men's Charter 2-Eye.......................... $90.00" << '\n';
cout << "5-  Defender 2-Eye Boat Shoe..................... $65.00" << '\n';
cout << "6-  Men's Embroidered Mako Short................. $34.99" << '\n';   //user friendly menu
cout << "7-  Men's Figawi Jacket.......................... $99.99" << '\n';
cout << "8-  Men's Mako Pant.............................. $45.99" << '\n';
cout << "9-  Check Out " << '\n';
cout << "0- Start Over and Erase all current sales information. "  << '\n';


cout << " " << '\n';
cout << "Please select the item you're interested in." << '\n'; 
cout << setprecision (5) << "Your current total is: $" << total << '\n'; //displays running total 
cin >> x; //allows entered value to take user to disired case statement

switch (x) //creates switch for the case statements
{
case '1':
    cout << "How many pairs would you like?" << '\n';
    cin >> amount;

    sub_total1 = (amount * seasonal);
    total = sub_total1 + total;                                 //case statements for getting the mula

    cout << "Your current total is: $" << total << '\n';


    break; //break statemets required to end case

case '2':

    cout << "How many pairs would you like?" << '\n';
    cin >> amount;

    sub_total2 = (amount * original);
    total = sub_total2 + total;

    break;

    case '3':

    cout << "How many pairs would you like?" << '\n';
    cin >> amount;

    sub_total3 = (amount * canoe);
    total = sub_total3 + total;

    break;

    case '4':

    cout << "How many pairs would you like?" << '\n';
    cin >> amount;

    sub_total4 = (amount * charter);
    total = sub_total4 + total;

    break;

    case '5':

    cout << "How many pairs would you like?" << '\n';
    cin >> amount;

    sub_total5 = (amount * defender);
    total = sub_total5 + total;

    break;

    case '6':

    cout << "How many pairs would you like?" << '\n';
    cin >> amount;

    sub_total6 = (amount * embroidered);
    total = sub_total6 + total;

    break;

    case '7':

    cout << "How jackets would you like?" << '\n';
    cin >> amount;

    sub_total7 = (amount * figawi);
    total = sub_total7 + total;

    break;

    case '8':

    cout << "How many pairs would you like?" << '\n';
    cin >> amount;

    sub_total8 = (amount * mako_pant);
    total = sub_total8 + total;


    break;

case '9':  //check out case statement, lets the function end

    cout << "Welcome to the check out, please finalize your order." << '\n';
    tax = total * .0875; //calculate tax
    cout << setprecision (5) << "Your total plus tax is: $" << (total = total + tax) << '\n'; //display total + tax
    cout << "Would you like your order to be shipped? (Type 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << '\n'; //allows choice for shipping or not
    cin >> shipping;

    if (shipping == '1')  //adds a shipping charge                                                                     
    {
        cout << "There is a flat shipping rate of $9.99" << '\n';
        cout << setprecision (5) << "Your new total is: $" << (total + 9.99) << '\n';
        cout << "Would you like a Receipt? (Press 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << '\n';
        cin >> receipt;


        if (receipt == '1')
        {
            cout << "                 " << "Your Receipt" << '\n';
cout << "Men's Authentic Original Seasonal Boat Shoe.."<< sub_total1 <<'\n';
cout << "Men's Authentic Original Suede Boat Shoe....."<< sub_total2 <<'\n';
cout << "Men's Mako 2-Eye Canoe Moc Boat Shoe........."<< sub_total3 <<'\n';
cout << "Men's Charter 2-Eye.........................."<< sub_total4 <<'\n';  //receipit
cout << "Defender 2-Eye Boat Shoe....................."<< sub_total5 <<'\n';
cout << "Men's Embroidered Mako Short................."<< sub_total6 <<'\n'; 
cout << "Men's Figawi Jacket.........................."<< sub_total7 <<'\n';
cout << "Men's Mako Pant.............................."<< sub_total8 <<'\n';
    cout << "If you have any questions please call (781)-452-2079."<< '\n';
    cout << "Thank you for shopping at The Sperry Store!" << '\n';
        }
        if (receipt == '2')
        {
            cout << "If you have any questions please call (781)-452-2079."<< '\n';
            cout << "Thank you for shopping at The Sperry Store!" << '\n';
        }


    }
    if (shipping == '2') //checks out without shipping
    {
                    cout << "                 " << "Your Receipt" << '\n';
cout << "Men's Authentic Original Seasonal Boat Shoe.."<< sub_total1 <<'\n';
cout << "Men's Authentic Original Suede Boat Shoe....."<< sub_total2 <<'\n';
cout << "Men's Mako 2-Eye Canoe Moc Boat Shoe........."<< sub_total3 <<'\n';
cout << "Men's Charter 2-Eye.........................."<< sub_total4 <<'\n';  //receipit
cout << "Defender 2-Eye Boat Shoe....................."<< sub_total5 <<'\n';
cout << "Men's Embroidered Mako Short................."<< sub_total6 <<'\n'; 
cout << "Men's Figawi Jacket.........................."<< sub_total7 <<'\n';
cout << "Men's Mako Pant.............................."<< sub_total8 <<'\n';
    cout << "If you have any questions please call (781)-452-2079."<< '\n';
    cout << "Thank you for shopping at The Sperry Store!" << '\n';
        }
        if (receipt == '2')
        {
            cout << "If you have any questions please call (781)-452-2079."<< '\n';
            cout << "Thank you for shopping at The Sperry Store!" << '\n';
        }

        no_ship(); //declares function

    }

    break;

    case '0':  //restart order statement

    cout << "Are you sure you would like to erase all data (This choice is non-reversable)?" << '\n';
    cout << "Press 1 for yes and 2 for no" << '\n';
    cin >> erase;

    if (erase == '1') //erases the data
    {
        shipping = 0;
        erase = 0;
        amount = 0;
        total = 0;          
        tax = 0;
        x = 0;
        sub_total1 = 0;
        sub_total2 = 0;
        sub_total3 = 0;
        sub_total4 = 0;
        sub_total5 = 0;
        sub_total6 = 0;
        sub_total7 = 0;
        sub_total8 = 0;
    }
    if (erase == '2') //returns to menu
    {
        cout << setprecision (4) << "Your current total is: $ " << total << '\n';  //returns user to the menu without erasing order
    }

    break;

    system("command/ccls");


}



while (x != '9'); //end of while loop (when x does not = 9)


return 0;
}

void no_ship() // displays the no_ship function data
{
    cout << "Your item will be ready in 1-2 business days." << '\n';
    cout << "If you have any questions please call (781)-452-2079."<< '\n';
    cout << "Thank you for shopping at The Sperry Store!" << '\n';
}
```

I apologize for such a long code but I have no idea where the error is.  Here is the error in the compiler:

```
Compiling...
final project.cpp
H:\Comp. Prog\final project.cpp(232) : error C2046: illegal case
Error executing cl.exe.
final project.exe - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: Pro tip - never put complex code inside a case in a switch. A case should consist of a couple of lines of code at most. Use functions, or use an if-ladder.

Comment: Which line is line 232? The (232) in the error message is telling you where the error is.

Comment: When you have a compilation problem that you cannot find, try reducing the size of (a copy of) your program until you find the problem. Eventually you either find the problem, or you have a 5-line program that you can show your teacher. For more information about this technique, see http://sscce.org.

Comment: I highly recommend a table of function pointers or calling functions within the `case` sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really work on your indentation, as it improves readability for you and others. Your problem is that `case '0':` is outside of the `switch` statement (with proper indentation that would have jumped at you).

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'll try to work on it. Are there any tutorials that I could look at?

Comment: @Matt: Here's one hint for you: never indent code within braces less than the braces themselves. If the lines get too long, break the lines. Better yet, break the code out into functions, as Neil suggested in his comment.

Answer (score 3):

You have too many closing braces, specifically the one immediately preceding `break; case '0':`.

This is closing off your `switch` statement which is why it's complaining about the naked `case`.

Having said that, the deletion of that extraneous brace will cause another problem since you then don't close off the switch statement at all. Immediately after the `case '0'` block, you close off the `do` loop without first closing off the `switch`. You'll need to put another `}` in there.

---

Might I suggest that you refactor your code to make it a little easier to read? In my opinion, `case` blocks should have a small number of lines in them (e.g., 10). Any more than that, or if there's a lot of indent levels, and it should just call a function to do the grunt-work.

That would have probably made your error more apparent since, if it didn't avoid it altogether, it would have at least moved it to the `case '9'` function.

Comment: When that's removed i get fatal error C1004: unexpected end of file found.  And two others.

Comment: Then you need another brace immediately before `while (x != '9');` - see my update.

Comment: Yes my structure is week, and I often stray away from functions because they give me issues...

Comment: @Matt And yet your avoidance of said functions gave you issues in this case. Hmmm. :-) I suspect it would be better to bite the bullet and learn to do it "properly".

Comment: Yes indeed >.<
I guess I should start....

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra closing brace in `case '9'`:

```
if (shipping == '2') //checks out without shipping
{
    // skipped
    } // <-------
    if (receipt == '2')
    {
        cout << "If you have any questions please call (781)-452-2079."<< '\n';
        cout << "Thank you for shopping at The Sperry Store!" << '\n';
    }

    no_ship(); //declares function

}
```